# Как не грузить картинку с сервера если она внутри спрятанного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="box" style="display: none;">
    <img src="/images/pic.jpg" alt="картинка">
</div>
```

Браузер загружает картинку с сервера, при этом она не будет показана пользователю.
Добавление `display: none;` к `img` не решает проблему.
Как можно попросить браузер подгружать картинку как только `div.box` изменится на `display: block;` и не грузить если установлено `display: none;` ?

Comment: в html вы указываете `<img src...` - браузер читает этот тег и загружает рис. если вы не хотите сразу загружать рис. то уберите этот тег. а когда решите показать box, то вставите img в div.

Comment: можно перехватывать изменение DOM, подписавшись на событие DOMSubtreeModified

Answer (score 1):

Думаю тебе как раз в тему [Управление загрузкой изображений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/189764/)

```
<div class="img">
        <img
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
            data-src="example.jpg"
        />
    </div>
```

Стоит заметить, что URL изображение задано в data-src, а не в src. Это необходимо, чтобы браузер не загружал картинку сразу. Вместо этого в src загружается прозрачный пиксель в GIF, заданный в base64, что уменьшает количество обращений к серверу.

Остается только при нужном событии изменить значение src на data-src.

```
        function loadimg(){
        var $images = $('.img');

        $images.each(function(){
            var $img = $(this),
                src = $img.attr('data-src');

            $img
                .on('load',imgLoaded($img[0]))
                .attr('src',src);
        });
    };


$(window).load(function(){
    loadimg();
};
```

Comment: _"в src загружается прозрачный пиксель"_ -- для чего так надо делать? можно же просто не загружать img.

Comment: c `img src` он же сразу прогрузит картинку, которую надо будет прятать. прозрачный пиксель послужит заглушкой для картинки которую надо подгрузить. Браузер не обратит на него внимание, а по нажатии сработает скрипт и загрузит целевой рисунок в нужный див. Хотя на велосипед похоже, но что поделать)

Comment: _"c img src он же сразу прогрузит картинку, которую надо будет прятать"_ -- а можно вообще не ставить `img`. т.е. будет просто пустой `<div class="box"></div>`, а из javascript добавить img и сменить значение display.

Comment: Вобщем-то ты прав. Вполне подходящий вариант и проще описанного мной

Comment: Что-то типа lazy load нужно вам выходит?

Comment: @Stack, но если отключить JS в браузере, то картинка не подгрузится вообще. Манипуляции с элементами на странице происходят уже после того как,  картинки были загружены браузером или можно как-то до загрузки изображения изъять его код с страницы, например, с помощью `.empty()`?

Comment: @Plush _"если отключить JS в браузере, то картинка не подгрузится вообще"_ -- в таком случае: <noscript><img src="..." /></noscript> - хотя такое может не работать. не проверял.

Comment: @Stack да, `<noscript><img src="..." /></noscript>` решает эту проблему.